# Do I have to add loopback-component-passport's core models manually?

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I installed `loopback-component-passport` so I can use it with strongloop's Loopback framework. I followed the [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=3836277),
but after this command: `npm install loopback-component-passport`, the following files/models are not created:

```
UserIdentity model
UserCredential model
ApplicationCredential model
```

These files are used by Loopback for third-party authentication. Do I have to add them manually? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to add them manually. You can refer this example, [loopback-example-passport](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport) on github.

The reason is **the relationships of loopback-component-passport's core models i.e `UserIdentity model`, `UserCredential` and `ApplicationCredential` with Loopback's core model `AccessToken` and `User` doesn't come preconfigured which is required for authentication.**

Also, you might notice that the developer extended the models but didn't added any `model.js`. This is so because there was no need to add any runtime logic. For starters, you might want to extend the core models as per the example and *create `relationship` and `acls` only*. Then you can proceed with custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think loopback built in models stay tucked away in node_modules, so assuming you mean that these tables are missing from your datastore, you can do an autoupdate in order to get loopback to build any missing tables.

I add the following code to a file in the `server/boot` directory when I need to during development.

```
module.exports = function(app, done) {
  app.datasources.mysql_db.autoupdate(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("autoupdate");
    done();
  })
}
```

Where `mysql_db` is the name of your datastore.

This will update the datasource when the server boot but shouldn't drop existing data (saying that I have seen instances where foreign keys are lost, so care & db backup is still needed).